# Power BI Desktop Pro - proceeding with this change will delete the existing refresh policy because it is no longer valid

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am setting up incremental refresh on a 3.7M row table and when I start the refresh, the following warning eventually comes up for this table: "Proceeding with this change will delete the existing incremental refresh policy because it is no longer valid." I can click Continue and the refresh appears to complete. However, if I refresh again, the same message comes up. Does anyone know why I would be getting this message? As far as I know, there was never an incremental refresh policy before I added in that one. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and my solution was to perform a preview refresh in Power Query for the two tables that I had this error with and after that they refreshed as normal. Not sure how/why but I was just glad the issue was sorted.